# Optional Variable Override in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-awx

I'm using AWX as a task runner to run a variety of Ansible modules. Some of the Ansible modules are third-party modules whose parameters I can't control without forking the module, which is undesirable for a variety of reasons.

AWX supplies `ansible_user` as one variable that is used by some of the modules I'm using, and I'm trying to allow a user to some hosts by setting another variable, `user_override`.

I first thought to simply add the line `ansible_user: "{{ user_override | default(ansible_user) }}"` to the task's parameters, which would work... but the modules in question don't accept credentials via parameters. My next thought was to add a `vars:` entry to the playbook and supply the override there via the same markup as above. This unfortunately results in the error `recursive loop detected in template string`, which has been the bane of my existence while working through this problem.

I've also tried using the if/else syntax and intermediate variables, but neither appear to solve this problem.

**How can I achieve this override functionality without forking AWX or the module in question?**

Mods: This is distinct from the pile of questions asking about simple variable defaulting because the existing questions aren't in the context of AWX or can be solved by simply using `default()` or `default(lookup())`.

Comment: [The documentation dealing with variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) takes your exact var as an example to illustrate the overall subject.

Comment: @Zeitounator, that's helpful, but I'm not sure how to use the precedence to solve this problem, which is overriding only sometimes. If I were running Ansible without AWX, precedence would easily solve the problem.

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you change the user in your awx task in that case ? Same as changing it on the command line. Or put it in your inventory for the group/hosts.... precedence rules are the same in bare ansible and awx. Awx only launches playbooks using the ansible command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I'm pretty sure that the thing I (the asker) was trying to do is intended to be done by just sometimes setting a value, but some challenging-to-anonymize constraints in our software make that somewhere between challenging and not an option.

A sideways solution to the particular problem of overriding the user is that AWX sets the username in `remote_user` as well as `ansible_user`, which is then used by `networkcli`. So you can use the line `remote_user: "{{ override_user | default(ansible_user) }}". This doesn't help *generally*, but does answer the question.